# How to write the solution for this problem in a better way

Tags: python, error-handling, nested-loops

How to solve this problem by python:

If a word contains two consecutive vowels(a,e,i,o,u,y), you must delete the second letter and then print the word.

I wrote this code, and I know that it is not completely correct, There are things that don't make sense.

Although it gives me the required result, I find that it is incorrect, because there are too many nested loops.

I want a better and easier code by python please.

```
def Convert(string):
    word = ["","","",""]
    word[:0] = string
    return word

word1 = str(input("Enter the word: ")).lower()
word = Convert(word1)
vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u","y"]
y = []

for i in range(1,len(word)-4):
  for j in range(5,len(vowels)):
    for x in range(6):
      for v in range(6):
       if word[i] == vowels[j-x] and word[i-1] == vowels[j-v]:                                                          
          word.remove(word[i])                                    
          print("".join(word))
          y.append("".join(word))
          break

if len(y)==0:
    print(word1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
VOWELS = "aeiouy"

def removeSecondVowel(word):
    for vowel in VOWELS:
        while 2 * vowel in word:
            word = word.replace(2 * vowel, vowel)

    return word

print(removeSecondVowel(input("Your word: ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I came up with.

```py
def twoVowels(word):
    vowels = set('aeiouy')
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] in vowels and i < len(word)-1 and word[i+1] in vowels:
            continue
        else:
            result += word[i]
    return result
      
print(twoVowels(input("Enter word: "))) # Enter word: bookkeeper
```

Result:
`bokkeper`